# PostgreSQL : relation [temp table] does not exist error for temporary table

Tags: postgresql

I have a function in PostgreSQL that calls multiple function depends on certain conditions. I create a temporary table in main function dynamically using "Execute" statement and using that temporary table for insertion and selection 
 in other functions (same dynamic process using "Execute" statement) those I am calling from main function.

However, its working fine as per my requirement. But sometimes it is throwing an error 'relation does not exists' on the temporary table when it is performing selection or insertion on the subroutine(internal function).

**SAMPLE**

- ***Main Function***

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sample_function(
          param bigint)
          RETURNS TABLE(isfinished boolean)
          LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
          COST 100.0
          VOLATILE     ROWS 1000.0
  AS $function$
      DECLARE
      st_dt DATE;
      end_dt DATE;
      var4 CHARACTER VARYING := CURRENT_TIME;
      var1 character varying;

  BEGIN

  SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(var4,':',''),'.',''),'+','') FROM 5 FOR 7) INTO var4;

  EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE sampletable'||var4||' ( 
      "emp_id" UUid,
      "emp_name" Character Varying( 2044 ),
      "start_date" Date,
      "end_date" Date)';


   select public.innerfunction (st_dt,end_dt,var4)
       into var1;


          EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE sampletable'||var4;

  return query select true ;

  END;
  ```

  ***- Inner Function***

  ```
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.innerfunction(
      st_dt timestamp without time zone,
      end_dt timestamp without time zone,
      var4 bigint)

  RETURNS integer
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
        COST 100.0

  VOLATILE

  AS $function$
  DECLARE

  date1 timestamp without time zone:=st_dt
  BEGIN

  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO sampletable'||var4||' 
  SELECT *
  from "abc"'
  ;
  return return_val;
  END;

  $function$;
  ```

  ***- Error Message***

  ```
  ERROR:  
  relation "sampletable1954209" does not exist
  LINE 1: INSERT INTO sampletable1954209 

  QUERY:  INSERT INTO sampletable1954209
  SELECT *
  from "abc"
  ;
  CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function innerfunction(timestamp without time zone, 
  timestamp without time zone) line 51 at EXECUTE
  SQL statement "SELECT public.innerfunction(st_dt ,end_dt)"
      PL/pgSQL function sample_function(bigint) line 105 at SQL statement
      ********** Error **********
  ```

In above example I created a main function '**sample_function**', and I am creating a temporary dynamic table '**sampletable** with a random number attached to it. I am using that table on '**innerfunction**' for insertion purpose.

When I am calling the main function it working as required but some times it gives the mentioned error '**relation "sampletable1954209" does not exist**'.

I am not able to catch the issue.

Comment: We want to see code, more code.

Comment: Sample code is attached above.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with much simpler code: `CREATE TEMP TABLE "unittest" ( LIKE "main_table" INCLUDING ALL ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS; SELECT * FROM "unittest";` - 2 out of 5 times it will complain `relation "unittest" does not exist`.  I'm running these queries through NodeJS too, so different language even.  It seems fine if I only have one DB connection, but if I have multiple connections active I'm much more likely to see the problem, even though those two statements are always run on the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem.  It turned out to be because the database was behind pgBouncer in transaction pooling mode, which meant each query could conceivably run in a different connection.

There were two symptoms of this behaviour:

1. I could run `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (LIKE sometable);` in one connection, and then run `SELECT * FROM test` in another connection and see the temporary table.  This isn't supposed to happen as temporary tables are meant to be session-specific, but because pgBouncer is pooling connections it means multiple sessions can share temporary tables unpredictably, if they are created outside of transactions.
2. Sometimes the connection would randomly change and my temporary table would disappear.  I was creating and accessing the temporary table outside of a transaction which is why pgBouncer thought it was ok to switch connections.

The solution is to wrap everything up inside a transaction, however this was problematic for me because I was calling other code that used transactions.  Postgres doesn't support nested transactions, so I was unable to wrap my code in one.  (It does approximate nested transactions with savepoints, but this requires your code to use different SQL if it's running inside a transaction or not, which is not practical.)

Another solution is to change the pgBouncer configuration to session pooling instead, which causes it to run the `DISCARD ALL` statement when a client disconnects, before giving the session to another client.  This drops all temporary tables and makes the connections behave more like direct connections.

There's a good write up of the issues at [the VMWare support hub](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/5000e00001iQdcb1586326422327?language=en_US).

Answer (score -1):

I see a problem with this code, but it does not quite match your exact error message:

You pass `var4` to `innerfunction` as `bigint`.

Now if `var4` starts with a zero like `0649940`, then `sample_function` will use `sampletable0649940`, while `innerfunction` will try to access `sampletable649940` because the leading zero is lost in the conversion.

Your error message has a seven-digit number though, so it might be a different problem.

Why don't you use a temporary table and use a fixed name for it? A temporary table is only visible in one session, and there cannot be any name collisions. That's what temporary tables are for.