# PostgreSQL ERROR: relation "temp" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I ran the following query

```
select bike_id, start_time, start_station, start_station_id, end_time, end_station, end_station_id, journey_distance    
from    
(   select bike_id, start_time, start_station_id, a.name as start_station, a.latitude as start_lat, a.longitude as start_lon,
    end_time, end_station_id, b.name as end_station, b.latitude as end_lat, b.longitude as end_lon,
    calculate_distance(a.latitude, a.longitude,  b.latitude, b.longitude,  'K') as journey_distance
    from baywheels_2019 
    left join baywheels_stations a on start_station_id = a.id
    left join baywheels_stations b on end_station_id = b.id
) temp
where journey_distance = (select max(journey_distance) from temp)
```

I got this error

```
ERROR:  relation "temp" does not exist
LINE 13: ...journey_distance = (select max(journey_distance) from temp) 
                                                                  ^
```

I searched stackoverflow but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168192/postgresql-relation-temp-table-does-not-exist-error-for-temporary-table) didn't help.

Can someone please explain what I did wrong and what the message `relation "temp" does not exist` meant?

Comment: Do you want the single row with the greatest `journey_distance` or do you expect several rows that tie and want them all?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use temp table in where clause as src table for another query.

Try to rewrite query using WITH clause:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-with.html

ex:

```
WITH temp as (   select bike_id, start_time, start_station_id, a.name as start_station, a.latitude as start_lat, a.longitude as start_lon,
    end_time, end_station_id, b.name as end_station, b.latitude as end_lat, b.longitude as end_lon,
    calculate_distance(a.latitude, a.longitude,  b.latitude, b.longitude,  'K') as journey_distance
    from baywheels_2019 
    left join baywheels_stations a on start_station_id = a.id
    left join baywheels_stations b on end_station_id = b.id
) 
select bike_id, start_time, start_station, start_station_id, end_time, end_station, end_station_id, journey_distance    
from temp 
where journey_distance = (select max(journey_distance) from temp)
```

Comment: To check my understanding, the `WHERE` clause can only be used with SRC or CTE tables? If `WITH temp as` is called `CTE`, do you know what `(select bike_id, ..., calculate_distance...) temp` is called? A *temp* variable? Thanks

Comment: I'd call `select bike_id, start_time, start_station_id, a.name as start_station, a.latitude as start_lat, a.longitude as start_lon,
    end_time, end_station_id, b.name as end_station, b.latitude as end_lat, b.longitude as end_lon,
    calculate_distance(a.latitude, a.longitude,  b.latitude, b.longitude,  'K') as journey_distance
    from baywheels_2019 
    left join baywheels_stations a on start_station_id = a.id
    left join baywheels_stations b on end_station_id = b.id
) temp` a subquery called `temp`.

Comment: I mean you can't use named temporary result set as src table in subquery inside where clause (postgres will not see this - it's a different context). *WITH temp as (   select...) and (select ... ) temp* - they are both "temporary result set" but with different context.